# Dashboard visualizing CPU usage of kafka container chopped up

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, grafana, promql, kafka-exporter

I want to monitor the cpu usage of kafka container, but the graph is chopped up into different pieces. There seem to be gaps in the graph and after each gap a different colored line follows. The time range is `last 30 days`. For the exporter we use `danielqsj/kafka-exporter:v1.4.2`

The promql query used to create this graph is:

**rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container="cp-kafka-broker"}[1m])**

Can I merge these lines into one continual? If so, with what promql expression/dashboard configuration?

[image: Grafana Dashboard CPU usage]

Answer (score 0):

This happens when at least 1 of the labels that are attached to the metric changes. The `rate` function keeps all the original labels from the underline time series. In Prometheus, each time series is uniquely identified by the metric name `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` and any labels (key-value pairs) attached to the metric (`container`, for instance). This is why Grafana uses different colors because they *are* different time series.

If you want to get a single series in Grafana you can aggregate using the `sum` operator:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container="cp-kafka-broker"}[1m]))
```

which by default will not keep any of the original labels.